# How does OpenMPI handle physical network topology?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

The best way to implement collective communications with individual send and receives depends on how the nodes are physically connected, by e.g. Infiband. I have not been able to find documentation on how to tell OpenMPI what network topology the supercomputer has, so I suppose it finds out automatically when doing collective communications. How does this work? In case "network topology" is the wrong search term, I mean things like fat tree, pruned tree, mesh, hypercube.

Comment: Network topology is irrelevant if you don't know how your application communicates. Most MPIs assign increasing ranks to successive entries in the hostlist. If your program is written so that processes with close ranks are also close in your application, that is not a bad design. There are a few MPI routines that have a parameter stating that renumbering is allowed, but support for that's experimental.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout My question applies specifically to collective communications, sorry if I did not make that clear enough. So MPI does know the exact communication pattern. The question was motivated by the following comment from "Introduction to high performance computing" by Chapman and Hall.


"Good MPI implementations are optimized for data flow on collective communication and (should) also have some knowledge about network topology built in."

Comment: You're asking specifically about OpenMPI which I have no experience with. Intel MPI has a ton of environment variables for setting the collective algorithms: ring, tree, binomial, all sorts of stuff. I imagine OpenMPI has that too. Look in the manual. I have no idea how much they tune that to the hardware that you install it on. Setting the default algorithm is probably done by the person installing the MPI software. (And yes, you mentioned "collective". I overlooked that.)